# Perform same conditional operation on multiple variables

Tags: r, variables, operation

In R, I often perform conditional operations on multiple variables. For example:

```
M_foo <- rnorm(25, 0, 1)
M_foo1 <- rnorm(25, 0, 1)
M_bar <- rnorm(25, 0, 1)
M_bar1 <- rnorm(25, 0, 1)
condition <- c(rep(0, 12), rep(1,13))

d <- as.data.frame(cbind(M_foo, M_bar, M_foo1, M_bar1, condition))

d$M_foo_new <- ifelse(
  d$condition == 0, d$M_foo1*2, NA
   )

d$M_bar_new <- ifelse(
  d$condition == 1, d$M_bar1*2, NA
)
```

If I do this for multiple variables that have systematically changing names, how can I condense this into a more compact workflow? 
For now, I often copy the code into MS Word and the search and change the respective differences in the variable name there. Can this be done more elegantly in R?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If we need to reuse, a function would be better

```
f1 <- function(dat, col1, val, col2, multiplier) {
   i1 <- dat[[col1]]==val
   ifelse(i1, dat[[col2]]*multiplier, NA)
}
f1(d, "condition", 0, "M_foo1", 2)
```

For multiple variable creation, use `lapply`

```
nm1 <- c("M_foo1", "M_bar1") 
d[paste0(nm1, "_new")] <- lapply(nm1, function(colN) f1(d, "condition", 0, col2 = colN, 2))
```

If the multiplier/val are different, then use `Map`

```
d[paste0(nm1, "_new")] <- Map(f1, dat = list(d), "condition", c(0,1), col2 = nm1, 2:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
d[,paste0(names(d[,1:2]),"_new")]=
          mapply(function(x,y) {x[d$condition!=y]=NA;x*2}, d[,3:4],unique(d$condition))
```